# Google Play Services v7.8 Nearby API AUTH_API_ACCESS_FORBIDDEN

Tags: android, google-play-services

Has anyone gotten the Google Play Services v7.8 Nearby API to work? I’m getting the status error below when I try to subscribe for messages. I've enabled the API and configured the key, etc. in the Developer Console as described [here](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-started).

`Status{statusCode=AUTH_API_ACCESS_FORBIDDEN, resolution=null}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the newest `NearBy API demo` and succeed.

You can just go [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/tree/master/messages/NearbyDevices) and clone it. Open it in Android Studio, and follow the following steps:

- Create a project on [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). Or, use an existing
  project.
- Click on `APIs & auth -> APIs`, and enable `Nearby Messages API`.
- Click on `Credentials`, then click on Create new key, and pick Android
  key. Then register your Android app's SHA1 certificate fingerprint
  and package name for your app. Use
  `com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.samples.nearbydevices` for the
  package name.
- You can get SHA1 by using: `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v` and the password by default is `android`.

[image]

- Copy the API key generated, and paste it in AndroidManifest.xml.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just updated to support library v23 and it is indeed working. I guess this qualifies as the answer.

Comment: Why with a different package name in the Google Console, the Nearby API it's not able to connect. I'm trying to do it with my application and it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether to make it as an answer.

But I scratched my head for 5 hours and figure out the issue.

I've more than 5 projects on my google API console.

Everything was perfect for the sample project.

But with actual project, I forgot to enable API :(